# How to avoid using regex in Cucumber-jvm Step Deifinition?

Tags: cucumber-jvm

Instead of having something like this:
    @Given("^I have (\d+) cukes in my belly$")
    public void i_have_cukes_in_my_belly(int cukes) throws Throwable {

Can we write the definition in this style below? The regex hurts my eyes.
@Given("I have $number cukes in my belly")
public void i_have_cukes_in_my_belly((Integer) cukes) throws Throwable {

Comment: You'd loose the guarantee of type checking on your parameter wouldn't you ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no you should do it

Long Answer: 
no, because

- as [ar3s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112637/ar3s) stated you woult lose your type safety for the int parameter
- the missing "^" and "$" would allow a possible missmatch: "OtherText I have 10 cukes in my belly OtherText" would also be matched, because "^" and "$" mark the beginning and the end of the matching text